# how to add a Discount price to the Invoice in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, price, invoice

In case the product is "In sales" I would like to have in the invoice the price before sales and the discounted price to appear in the invoice. How to do that. Thanks

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should lookup in **app/design/frontend/(theme_name)/default/template/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml**
There should be a section with item price - it varies depending of template you use. There you are able to put the code to display regular price.